# Cálculo de Latitude e Longitude - Aproximidade

Tags: mysql, select, geolocalização, geometria

Galera estou com uma pequena bronca...

Atualmente eu tenho os dados Latitude e Longitude de cadastros de empresas em meu banco de dados, com isto preciso trazer dados próximos a mim, no caso teria latitude e longitude da minha posição, por exemplo, trazer empresas que estão a 10 metros de distancias de mim, a dúvida é "Como fazer"?

Encontrei na internet alguns Selects, mas não tive sucesso mesmo limitando para "10 metros" ele me retorna dados lá da caixa prego.
Isto para vários selects.

Gostaria de ver com a comunidade se alguem já mexeu com isso e se tem algo funcionando que poderia compartilhar.. :D

Agradeço a atenção e ajuda antecipadamente!

Answer (score 3):

Existe uma equação utilizada na navegação que fornece a distância a partir de dois pontos, ou seja, a partir da latitude e longitude é possível calcular a distância de um determinado ponto.

O nome dessa técnica é a  fórmula de **Haversine**.

Exemplo:

1- Criando a tabela

CREATE TABLE `enderecos` (
 `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY ,
 `nome` VARCHAR( 60 ) NOT NULL ,
 `endereco` VARCHAR( 80 ) NOT NULL ,
 `lat` FLOAT( 10, 6 ) NOT NULL ,
 `lng` FLOAT( 10, 6 ) NOT NULL
) ;

2 - Inserindo os dados

```
INSERT INTO `cake`.`enderecos` (`id`, `nome`, `endereco`, `lat`, `lng`) VALUES
(NULL, 'Shopping Iguatemi Porto Alegre', 'Av. João Wallig, 1800 - Passo da Areia, Porto Alegre - RS', '-30.027668', '-51.163269'),
(NULL, 'Bourbon Shopping', 'Av. Assis Brasil, 164 - São João, Porto Alegre - RS', '-30.007913', '-51.184273'),
(NULL, 'Praia De Belas Shopping', 'Av. Praia de Belas, 1181 - Praia de Belas, Porto Alegre - RS', '-30.049527', '-51.228753'),
(NULL, 'Barra Shopping Sul', 'Av. Diário de Notícias, 300, Porto Alegre - RS', '-30.084494', '-51.245297'),
(NULL, 'Shopping TOTAL', 'Av. Cristóvão Colombo, 545 - Floresta, Porto Alegre - RS', '-30.025511', '-51.212344')
```

3 - consulta SQL

```
SELECT id,
(6371 * acos(
 cos( radians(-30.053831) )
 * cos( radians( lat ) )
 * cos( radians( lng ) - radians(-51.191810) )
 + sin( radians(-30.053831) )
 * sin( radians( lat ) ) 
 )
) AS distancia
FROM enderecos
HAVING distancia < 25
ORDER BY distancia ASC
LIMIT 4;
```

Como a fórmula é aplicada sobre uma esfera, é necessário informar o raio. O número 6371 diz respeito ao raio aproximado do planeta Terra, em quilômetros. Caso queira realizar o cálculo em milhas, utilize 3959. A consulta é ordenada por distância crescente, ou seja, mais próximos primeiro.

4 - Resultado

Os resultados retornados estão funcionando perfeitamente. Não esqueça que essas distâncias são marcadas em linha reta, ou seja, se você for estabelecer um percurso de carro, é bastante provável que a distância aumente devido ao trajeto que deve ser feito.

> id     distancia
>   3   3.5876619973975385
>   5   3.7180529211314073
>   1   4.001380483066799
>   2   5.15708294670291

Dessa forma, conseguimos coletar os endereços mais próximos do ponto referenciado. Todos os endereços são próximos, então uma listagem sem limitação traria os 5 endereços, pois estão dentro do raio de 25km.

> Fonte de pesquisa: http://www.phpit.com.br/artigos/como-procurar-locais-proximos-usando-sql.phpit
>   https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/F%C3%B3rmula_de_Haversine

Comment: Lunar agradeço sua resposta, e me tira a dúvida no caso ali aquele 25 é 25km? se eu colocar 1 por exemplo será 1km certo? e para eu pegar os dados a 10 metros próximos a mim eu altero ali no inicio o valor 6371 para 3959 ?

Comment: Milha e KM são unidades de comprimentos, porém a milha é adotada em países de língua inglesa, como Inglaterra e Estados Unidos.
Uma milha corresponde, aproximadamente, a 1,609 quilômetros ou 1609 metros, se você mudar o raio para milhas deverá informar a medida em milhas na clausulá having.
10 metros equivale a aproximadamente 0.00621371 milhas

Answer (score -1):

Peguei uma latitude e longitude qualquer aqui no Google Maps.

-23.575546 
-46.665508

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Monte a URL com esses dados:

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=-23.57546,-46.66508&sensor=true
```

E terá o endereço exato em JSON

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Desculpe Reginaldo me expressei mal na minha dúvida, não quero pegar dados da google, mas sim do banco de dados que tenho, atualmente tenho um cadastro de varias empresas com lat e lng de cada um, a partir do meu ponto preciso mostrar as empresas mais proximas.

Comment: Tranquilo. É provavel que eu tenha me apressado também e resolvi o que você não queria. De qualquer forma, dá para utilizar esse serviço do Google também. A rotina iria ler sua tabela, montar a URL de consulta e tratar os dados que receber.
Olha as opcões:

https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/details

Comment: Opá bacana estarei dando uma analisada também, agradeço novamente a sua prontidão na resposta!